# biholomorphism $g:G\rightarrow \mathbb C$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $G\subset \mathbb C$ and $g:G \rightarrow \mathbb C\;\;$ biholomorphic. Prove that $G=C$

My attempt at this is the following : Let $f\in Aut(C)\;\;\;$ then $\;(f\circ g)(z)=cz+d=cg(z)+d\;$
Hence $g(z)=z$

Am I doing it totally wrong ? Would appreciate some help.

Comment: Are you allowed to use the Riemann mapping theorem?

Comment: @carmichaelI561 am allowed to use the rieman mapping Theorem but I am also intrested in a solution to the problem that uses the fact at all injective holomorphic funtions on $\mathbb C$ have the form $f(z)=az+b$

Comment: @XPenguen, yes you do not need to assume RMT.

Answer (score 2):

Let $i:G\hookrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ denote the canonical inclusion. Then $i \circ g^{-1}:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ is an injection, and therefore, $$i \circ g^{-1}(z)=az+b,~~~~a\in\mathbb{C_*},b\in\mathbb{C}$$

It follows that $i=ag+b$, and since $g$ is a surjection, so is $i$. That the inclusion map is surjective implies that $G=\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

$g^{-1}$ is an entire function, so it's range can miss at most one point( Picard Theorem). But $g$ is an homeomorphism also and we get $G$ must be $\mathbb C$.

Comment: Why is $g(G) = \mathbb{C}$?